# Break an array into smaller arrays, using a specific character as a break point

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
  [ 3, 8, 18, '-', 19, 3, 8, 20, 19, 3, 8, '-', 22 ]
```

I want to break it into subarrays based on where the '-' is, so it would look like this:

```
  [ [3, 8, 18], [19, 3, 8, 20, 19, 3, 8], [22] ]
```

I need to write a function to do this for other similar arrays.

I have tried using the slice method but I can't quite figure out how to make it work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The `slice()` method should work. Get the index of the `-` element, than use that as the end of the slice.

Comment: Show how you tried to solve it with `slice()`. Then we can show where you went wrong and how to fix it. But we're not going to do it from scratch for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate over your array and fill a temp-array with the content, when you find your special split-character, you can push the temp array into a result-array, empty the temp-array and then continue the loop.

```js
let data = [ 3, 8, 18, '-', 19, 3, 8, 20, 19, 3, 8, '-', 22 ];

let result = [];
let temp = [];

for (let item of data) {
  if (item == '-') {
    result.push(temp);
    temp = [];
  } else {
    temp.push(item);
  }
}
result.push(temp);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling to understand how I could iterate over the array to do this. But I see from your very clear answer that I will be pushing the numbers into temp [] until we get to the '-' and at that point we push the filled temp into result, and then reset the temp to an empty array to continue on down the line. The logic was hard for me to get on my own but hopefully I can learn from this, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for:

```
l =  [ 3, 8, 18, '-', 19, 3, 8, 20, 19, 3, 8, '-', 22 ];

let res = [];
let subres = [];

l.forEach((n, index) => {
  if (n !== '-') {
    subres.push(n);
  } else {
    res.push(subres);
    subres = [];
  }

  if (index === l.length - 1 && subres.length >= 1) {
      res.push(subres);
    }
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [3, 8, 18, '-', 19, 3, 8, 20, 19, 3, 8, '-', 22];
const res = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr == "-" ? acc.push([]) : acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
  return acc;
}, [[]]);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a function to do this for you and either inside use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through each of the elements and "group" based on the location of a passed in character.

```js
var data = [ 3, 8, 18, '-', 19, 3, 8, 20, 19, 3, 8, '-', 22 ]

let chunkByChar = (arr, char) => {
  let result = [[]]
  arr.forEach(x => x === char ? result.push([]) : result[result.length-1].push(x))
  return result
}

console.log(chunkByChar(data, '-'))
console.log(chunkByChar(data, 8))
console.log(chunkByChar(data, 3))
```